What is the point of a router sending an arp request to another router
Routers operate on Layer 3. So why can’t routers just send messages to eachother via IP? Why do they have to send an arp for the other router’s mac address? Also I heard when a router sends an arp to another router it is sent directly. I don’t understand this either. It’s like sending a letter to a friend asking for their home address. Why not just send the original message in the first place if you already had a way to get it to their location?
